# ant task to run JUnit tests from a jar (but only files that have tests!)

Tags: junit, ant

We're using JUnit inside a custom framework to test an applications behaviour. We're not actually doing unit testing, just leveraging JUnit.

I've created an ant task to run all the tests in the jar file, but unfortunately it's trying to run *everything* as a JUnit test. Since the jar file contains things besides just the tests (it contains the supporting framework) this is a problem.

Is there a way to make the junit task only run things marked as tests (we use @Test)?

Currently my ant task looks like this:

```
<target name="test">
    <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="no">
        <classpath refid="library.third-party.classpath" />
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${basedir}/build/jar/fidTester.jar" />
        </classpath>

        <formatter type="plain" />
        <formatter type="xml" />

        <batchtest fork="no" todir="${basedir}/reports">
            <zipfileset src="${basedir}/build/jar/fidTester.jar" includes="**/tests/**/*.class" />
        </batchtest>

    </junit>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Ant JUnit Task documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html):

`skipNonTests`

> Do not pass any classes that do not contain JUnit tests to the test
>   runner. This prevents non tests from appearing as test errors in test
>   results. Tests are identified by looking for the @Test annotation on
>   any methods in concrete classes that don't extend
>   junit.framework.TestCase, or for public/protected methods with names
>   starting with test in concrete classes that extend
>   junit.framework.TestCase. Classes marked with the JUnit 4
>   org.junit.runner.RunWith or org.junit.runner.Suite.SuiteClasses
>   annotations are also passed to JUnit for execution, as is any class
>   with a public/protected no-argument suite() method.